# How to draw a coordinate system with LaTeX?

Tags: diagrams, arrows, technical-drawing, coordinates

I want to draw a coordinate system like this:

[image]

I would like to specify the width and height of the coordinate system and where the origin begins (upper left corner). I also want to specify the x and y axes with arrows. Additionally the end of the x and y axis should be indicated with the text "200px".

I'm a LaTeX beginner and am not sure how to do that.

Can anyone recommend a latex package for it?

Comment: The first choices would be [TikZ](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) or [PsTricks](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/), associated with TikZ you also have [pgfplots](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: You should look into the package [`pgf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) (also named `tikz` in its front-end layer) or [`pstricks`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pstricks). Both have amazing drawing capabilities and support just what you request.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The TikZ package is great! I did the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

    % TikZ picture with origin upper left
    \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1] 
        % 4x4 grid
        \draw (0, 0) grid (4, 4);
        % origin point
        \draw [color=blue, fill=blue] (0, 0) circle (0.1);
        % x-axis
        \draw [thick,->] (0, 0) -- (4.5, 0);
        % y-axis
        \draw [thick,->] (0, 0) -- (0, 4.5);
        % origin label
        \node at (-0.1, -0.5) {(0, 0)};
        % x-axis label
        \node at (4.5, -0.5) {200px};
        % y-axis label
        \node at (0, 5) {200px};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Very helpful:
[A brief introduction into TikZ](http://www.wv.inf.tu-dresden.de/Teaching/SS-2012/howto/tikz-introduction.pdf)

Comment: This seems to make the boxes checkboxes. If I click one of them in Preview, a checkmark appears.

Comment: The "brief introduction into TikZ" seems to be down.

Comment: @J_F_B_M You are right! Luckily there is a copy of it here: http://www.computational-logic.org/content/study/master/documents/softskills_tikz.pdf

Answer (score 26):

Tikz or pstricks are more powerful but LaTeX has a built in coordinate drawing system, and you really don't need to load an external package for this (although I loaded color)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\setlength\unitlength{10pt}

\begin{picture}(20,10)(0,-10)
\thicklines
\put(0,0){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(0,0){\line(0,-1){10}}
\put(0,-10){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(20,0){\line(0,-1){10}}
\put(0,0){\circle*{.3}}
\put(0,0){\vector(1,0){4}}
\put(0,0){\vector(0,-1){4}}
\thinlines
\put(0,0){\makebox(0,0)[tl]{\tiny(0,0)}}
\put(4,0){\makebox(0,0)[cb]{\tiny x}}
\put(0,-4){\makebox(0,0)[cr]{\tiny y`}}
\color[rgb]{.8,.8,.8}
\multiput(1,0)(1,0){19}{\line(0,-1){10}}
\multiput(0,-1)(0,-1){9}{\line(1,0){20}}

\end{picture}%


\end{document}
```

Comment: It's good that this has a non-TikZ answer, but I feel like this is a good example of why bloated packages like TikZ or PSTricks are useful even for rather simple tasks. Man, code for graphics with plain LaTeX is *scary*!

Comment: Thank you for this! It's good to know that the standard can do this. But I prefer the TikZ-way. :)

Answer (score 6):

With PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=18pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}{gridlabels=0pt,griddots=0}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](5,-5)
    \psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(5,-5)[200px,90][200px,-90]
    \pscircle*(0,0){2pt}
    \uput[90](0,0){$(0,0)$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is also possible to create non-orthogonal coordinate system with PSTricks as follows. Here, `OI` and `OJ` are the unit vectors that are parallel to `x` and `y` axes, respectively.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=18pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}{gridlabels=0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](5,-5)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={135,45,180}]
        (0,0){O}
        (1;-15){I}
        (1;-75){J}
    \pstOIJGeonode[PointName=none,PointSymbol=none](5,0){I'}{O}{I}{J}(0,5){J'}
    \pstOIJGeonode[PosAngle={-45,45},PointName={{R(4,2)},{A(4,0)},{B(0,2)}},PointNameSep=2em](4,2){R}{O}{I}{J}(4,0){A}(0,2){B}
    \psline[linecolor=cyan]{->}(O)(I')
    \psline[linecolor=cyan]{->}(O)(J')
    \uput[-15](I'){$x$}
    \uput[-75](J'){$y$}
    \psline[linecolor=orange](A)(R)(B)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It might be unavailable in TikZ or others.

### Warning

The syntax of `\pstOIJGeonode` is a bit uncommon as follows.

```
\pstOIJGeonode(x1,x2){A1}{O}{I}{J}(x2,y2){A2}...(xn,yn){An}
```

The first point `A1` must come right after `\pstOIJGeonode` but the remaining points `A2`, ..., `An` must come right after `{O}{I}{J}`. I don't know why the author made such a strange syntax.